# Can't save to disk after rooting device

Tags: applications, root-access

I have rooted my Android 5.0.2 (Samsung Tab 8.4 Pro, TM700) the day before yesterday, and I noticed yesterday that my Chrome won't save files anymore, at all. I then installed Firefox, same behaviour. WhatsApp, can't download images or videos. My mail application downloads files just fine, so I am not sure what is going on here. What do I need to check for? Could it be permissions on some folder, and if so, what folder to check?

Comment: Try checking the permissions on your downloads folder and your sd card. use es file Explorer

Comment: is this internal or external storage?

Comment: The download folder is not on the SD card, so internal. Although I wasn't able to find it via ls so far, no idea where the default folder for that stuff is. ES Explorer asked for root permissions to change files on the SD card, and then was able to do so. How can I give an application root rights, or should I chmod the folders to 777?

Comment: I checked the /sdcard folder (since this is where downloads is), and the rights are lrwxrwxrwx, so every program should be able to write there. Edit: every subfolder there is lrwxrwx--- so no app without ownership can write there it seems.

Comment: yeah, I thought that was probably not the problem, but what is the problem in double checking?

Comment: the default download folder is /mnt/sdcard/Downloads/

Comment: I just rechecked, the subfolders dont have permissions on them and belong to root. Guess I will try changing each folders permission

Comment: use a batch script for the job. shall i make this an answer?

Comment: How do I change the permissions? I have done "chmod 777 Download", yet nothing has changed there. Is there some other way to do it properly? I have su earlier

Comment: You can use rwxrwxrwx for chmod instead of the code. check letter codes for chmod on Google. or manually do it using es file Explorer

Comment: Can you make it an answer? It says "Bad mode" when using rwxrwxrwx as chmod parameter. And ES Explorer says, the folder is Write and Read enabled. But the permissions are rwxrwx--- only.

Comment: Okay, I just installed root browser, and it said that it couldn't change permission on that folder, which is in line with everything I have seen so far. Why on earth can't I change permission on my download folder? I want every application to be able to access it.

Comment: u need to chown to user first. only if u are the owner can u change the permission. rebooting in rooted devices does this. Probably your root is bad. root the device again after completely uninstalling supersu or whatever you use.

Comment: the chmod rwxrwxrwx isn't exactly like that. check the bash manual page for the correct format

Comment: i don't remember it atm

Comment: Try adb or if all else fails, twrp recovery. twrp Explorer has an option for chmod 777. I recommend you reroot

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a Terminal Emulator. The 'su' command is for becoming the root user and the next one fixes all the permissions.

```
su
restorecon -v -R /data/media
```

Comment: Only SELinux context, not all the permissions.